# How to make VSCode use a different window for different subtree?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use different git worktree or repo at the same time and I would like to configure VScode so that when I call it with
`code <filename>` it shows in the same window file belonging to a repo/subtree but use different windows for different subtrees..

Is-there an existing extension which does this?

If not, do you think it's possible to create one ? How could a 'shell/python script' ask a specific VScode window to open a file in a new tab?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure an extension is really needed: opening different window (code -n) and configuring one project for each window, calling code  seem to add the file to the right window..
Either there was an improvement, or I didn't configured correctly the projects before..